# How do I join on a filter instead of a key?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a list of actions per year, like so -

```
print(df)

      id        actions      year       
      b           2       1995 
      c           156     1997 
      e           53      1996 
      f           109     1994
```

I'd like to make a list of who had the most actions up to each year, so that it looks like this -

```
print(output)

      asofyear        id      actions      rank       
      1994            f       109          1
      1995            f       109          1
      1995            b       2            2
      1996            f       109          1
      1996            e       53           2
      1996            b       2            3
      1997            c       156          1
      1997            f       109          2
      1997            e       53           3
      1997            b       2            4
```

How do I do this join where it ranks every `id` for the `id` values with a year that is less than the `asofyear`. One idea I was thinking about was something like this -

```
asOfYear <- seq(as.Date("1995-01-01"),as.Date("2000-01-01"),by="year")

asOfYear %>% 
    left_join(df, by = (asOfYear <= year)) %>%
    arrange(asofyear, actions) %>%
    group_by(asofyear) %>% 
    mutate(rank = row_number())
```

I don't know how to make that join key work though, but I would like to do this with `dplyr`.

Comment: Try with `left_join(df, by = "year")`

Comment: The problem is that I need my groups to include records that include each year and every year prior.

Comment: can you join, then filter afterwards?

Comment: I don't get you desired output. E.g. `id = b` is `year = 1995` but your desired output has `b` for 1995 and two years later not one year prior.

Comment: Each year in the first column says "As of this year, give me a list of all of the `ID`s, their actions and rank them in descending order"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R method using `lapply`, assuming you have unique years in `df` we can filter the daraframe for each `year`, order them by `action` column and add a `rank` column giving the row number.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(sort(df$year), function(x) {
     temp = df[df$year <= x, ]
     transform(year = x,temp[order(temp$actions,decreasing = TRUE), ], 
               rank = 1:nrow(temp))  
}))

#   id actions year rank
#4   f     109 1994    1
#41  f     109 1995    1
#1   b       2 1995    2
#42  f     109 1996    1
#3   e      53 1996    2
#11  b       2 1996    3
#2   c     156 1997    1
#43  f     109 1997    2
#31  e      53 1997    3
#12  b       2 1997    4
```

---

If we want to do it using `tidyverse` tools we can do

```
map_dfr(sort(df$year), function(x) 
          df %>% 
           filter(year <= x) %>%
           arrange(desc(actions)) %>%
           mutate(year = x, 
                  rank = row_number()))


#   id actions year rank
#1   f     109 1994    1
#2   f     109 1995    1
#3   b       2 1995    2
#4   f     109 1996    1
#5   e      53 1996    2
#6   b       2 1996    3
#7   c     156 1997    1
#8   f     109 1997    2
#9   e      53 1997    3
#10  b       2 1997    4
```

**How the `tidyverse` approach works :**

Any type of `map..` is used to loop over each element passed (here `year`). `map_dfr` means that it expects the output of each operation to be a dataframe (`df` of `map_dfr`) and it will rbind all the dataframe outputs together (`r` of `map_dfr`), there is also `map_dfc` which cbinds the output.

Now for every `year` it `filters` the `df` for `year` values which is less than equal to the current value (`x`), then arranges the dataframe in a descending (`desc`) order based on values in `actions`. Creates two new columns using `mutate`, first which is `year` (the already existing `year` column is replaced) gets the current value of `year` which is `x` and the `rank` column gives an incremental row number for every row in the dataframe.

To understand, the operation in detail I would advise you to run manually the steps for each `year`.

So for first year `1994` it gives output as

```
df %>% 
  filter(year <= 1994) %>%
  arrange(desc(actions)) %>%
  mutate(year = 1994, 
         rank = row_number())

#  id actions year rank
#1  f     109 1994    1
```

For `1995` it gives output

```
df %>% 
  filter(year <= 1995) %>%
  arrange(desc(actions)) %>%
  mutate(year = 1995, 
         rank = row_number())

#  id actions year rank
#1  f     109 1995    1
#2  b       2 1995    2
```

and so on this iterates for every `year`. So for every `year` you will get such dataframes and we rbind the final output together.

Comment: It doesn't look like the output matches up.

Comment: @Cauder sorry, did not notice the `year` column. Should be ok now?

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there any way to do with with `dplyr`?

Comment: @Cauder added an option with `tidyverse`.

Comment: I'd like to understand what the function does in pieces. This is my understanding: `map_dfr` makes a new data frame, according to the output from the arguments. the first argument sorts the data frame by year, ascending and the second argument is an anonymous function that creates a rank by actions for each year. Essentially, it calculates this individually (making the rank for each AsOfYear) and then uses map_dfr to put it all together. Is that right? Is map_dfr assembling individual outputs from the function or combining the outputs with the original dataframe?

Comment: @Cauder `map_dfr` assembles all the output together. I have added some explanation, see if it is helpful.